# Are there any other balance management systems other than UTXOs and Account Based used by blockchains today?

Tags: blockchain, altcoin, utxo, balance

To know how much balance a user has on the bitcoin blockchain you just need to look at their UTXOs. To do the same in Ethereum you just look at their accounts. Are there any other systems used by notable blockchains?

Comment: Sorry if this isn't the right place to post the question, but I'm not sure where to post blockchain-generic questions.